# bash - while loop - rolling 2 dice

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a bash script that rolls 2 dice(with 6 sides). When the 2 dice hits double sixes I want the script to stop (break) and count how many rolls it took to get double sixes.

```
#!/bin/bash
DOUBLESIX="6-6"

while (( 0 ==0 )) ; do
     dice=$RANDOM; ((dice = dice % 6 )); (( dice = dice +1 ))
     dice2=$RANDOM; ((dice2 = dice2 % 6 )); (( dice = dice + 1))

pair="$dice-dice$2"
echo $pair

if [[ "$pair" == "$DOUBLESIX" ]]; then
      break
fi

done

echo "It took $count rolls to get 6-6 "
```

Here's what i have so far.  Question is, how do I count how many times the while loop ran and put it in my $count?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure those loop checks are OK?

Comment: If you called the first one "dice1=" instead of just "dice=", then you wouldn't have conflicting names when you have "dice2" :)

Comment: If you use braces around your variable names `${foo}` like paxdiablo does in his answer you won't run into name collisions like racraman warns about.

Answer (score 2):

I won't comment too much on the other potential issues you have with your code, such as the `dice$2` "variable", or the fact you can generate a random number between one and six inclusive with the somewhat simpler `((num = $RANDOM % 6 + 1))` - the learning process of fixing/improving those is what will make you a better coder.

---

But, for the specific question on how to maintain a count, that's relatively simple. Before the loop starts, insert the following code to initialise the count to zero:

```
((count = 0))
```

Then, with each roll of the two dice, use the following to increment the count:

```
((count = count + 1))
```

An example of how to do this can be seen below. It's for counting from one to ten but you should get the idea:

```
((count = 1))
while [[ ${count} -le 10 ]] ; do
    echo $count
    ((count = count + 1))
done
```

---

For what it's worth (don't use this if this is a classwork problem, you'd be crazy to think educators don't search the net for plagiarism), here's how I would implement such a beast:

```
#!/bin/bash

DESIRED="6-6"
((count = 0))
dice="NOT ${DESIRED}"
while [[ "${dice}" != "${DESIRED}" ]] ; do
    ((count = count + 1))
    ((die1 = $RANDOM % 6 + 1))
    ((die2 = $RANDOM % 6 + 1))
    dice="${die1}-${die2}"
    echo ${dice}
done

echo "It took ${count} rolls to get ${DESIRED}"
```

Comment: bash also has `((count++))` if brevity has worth.

Comment: thank you! I just added the count bits in my current one and it works.
yours is surely a beast =]

Comment: I'd be inclined to use something like a colon or space or something other than the subtraction operator to separate the values. Not so much for functionality, but for a later reader of the code.  :)

Comment: @danny, I used `-` because that's what the OP used. It may be that a different character may be better, I decline to comment on that :-)

Comment: Bah. "Reading the original question." :D

Answer (score 1):

I advice to use `shuf` for this purpose.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
declare -i count=1
while [ "6 6" != "$(shuf --input-range='1-6' -r -n 2 | xargs)" ]; do
    (( ++count ))
done
echo "It took $count rolls to get double six."
```

To generating two random numbers between 1 and 6 we use

```bash
    shuf --input-range='1-6' -r -n 2
```

`shuf [OPTION]... [FILE]` write  a  random permutation of the input lines to standard output. Each output permutation is equally likely. `-i lo-hi` or `--input-range=lo-hi` act as if input came from a file containing the range of unsigned decimal integers `lo-hi`, one per line. `-r` or `--repeat` repeat output values, that is, select with replacement. With this option the output is not a permutation of the input; instead, each output line is randomly chosen from all the inputs. `-n count` or `--head-count=count` output at most `count` lines  (by default, all input lines are output). If `--head-count` is not given, shuf repeats indefinitely.

Type `man shuf` or see [coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html#shuf-invocation) for more details.